EF Core not able to run if a trigger exists on a table
I have a .NET 8 Function App that connects to an Azure SQL Server. It uses Entity Framework Core to insert/update to a table.
Recently another team member added a trigger on a table that I'm referencing, and once he did, my apps failed to run. I then re-scaffold the table in my project which added a line in the DataContext.OnModelCreating function
entity.ToTable("tablename", tb => tb.HasTrigger("triggername")

That fixed my issue and I was able to run my app in non-prod.
However, now I need to move that code to Prod, but that trigger hasn't been added to the Prod table just yet. So, I'm trying to find a way that I can push the code without reference to the trigger.
In my local development, if I comment out that entity.ToTable reference in the DataContext, it fails again. I can't seem to figure out how or if it’s even possible for the DataContext to reference the table without it referencing the trigger.
My other concern is that if someone adds a trigger to a table, then it will potentially break the app. That would mean that if, for example, I had 10 Function Apps referencing that table in Prod, we will have to immediately update those 10 apps as soon as the trigger is added to the table.
Is there any way around that?

When things fail to run, they will have error logs, we can't magically see them from here I'm afraid. Either way, you need to provide more information, some code, a [mre] would be best.

You can safely push your code, right now HasTrigger has effect only on Inserts and Updates. Also you can reuse the following answer to set HasTrigger to all tables.

Hi @Caverman, have you tried to  use the --no-triggers option with dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold to prevent EF Core from generating trigger-related configuration in your model when re-scaffolding? e.g dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "YourConnectionString" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --context "YourContext" --no-triggers

@SvyatoslavDanyliv thanks for the article you sent. For testing purposes I pushed my code out to PROD without the trigger just to see what would happen and as you said it worked because of the added "tb.HasTrigger('sometriggername')". Afterwards I had the db team add the trigger to the table because we are going to need it soon.
